# How to show Rive animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flare, rive

I'm trying to show an animation from my riv flare. It was really simple in FlareActor and flr file. But can't show my animation with riv. I have 2 animations in my riv file. They are anim1 and anim2. I'm trying to show anim1 as default. Then trying to change it according to conditions. Here is my code snippet.

```
  late RiveAnimationController? _controller;
  Artboard? _riveArtboard;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadRiveFile();
  }

  void _loadRiveFile() async {
    await rootBundle.load('assets/animations/anim_file.riv').then(
          (data) async {
        final file = RiveFile.import(data);
        final _artboard = file.mainArtboard;
        _artboard.addController(_controller = SimpleAnimation('anim1'));
        setState(() => _riveArtboard = _artboard);
      },
    );
  }
```

This is build func:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => {getStatus},
  child: _riveArtboard == null ? const SizedBox.shrink(): Rive(artboard: _riveArtboard!))),
```

What I'm missing? Or how can I show my animation? Also I tried set controllers but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Rive provides `StateMachineController` to switch between animations.  If you wish to use `SimpleAnimation` you can follow this way.

```dart
  // on state class
  RuntimeArtboard _riveArtboard = RuntimeArtboard();
  final SimpleAnimation anim1 = SimpleAnimation('anim1');
  final SimpleAnimation anim2 = SimpleAnimation('anim2');
```

To  change between animation, you need to remove previous controllers and add the one you like to animate.

```dart
  playAnim2(){
   _riveArtboard.artboard..removeController(anim1)
   ..addController(anim2);
 }
```

You can take a visit on [this repository](https://github.com/yeasin50/BasicBankSystem/blob/master/lib/screens/dash_rive.dart) that follow this pattern.

I will encourage you to use `StateMachineController`

In this case, you need some sort of input value while implementing animation on rive.

On dart level,

```dart
 /// on state class
  StateMachineController? controller;
  SMIInput<bool>? isAnim1; // true from rive
  Artboard? _riveArtboard;
```

All you need to provide `isAnim1.value= false` based on your scenario, and it will switch the animation.

Check [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69062813/10157127) and [GitHub repository](https://github.com/yeasin50/Rive_state_machine_example) .