# How to toggle rive animation when tapped on the animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, rive

I am a beginner to `rive` and `flutter`. I am building a favorite items page in `flutter`. If there are not anything added to favorites I need to show a `riveAnimation` on screen. I already implemented almost everything to show the `animation` on screen. But I need to toggle a jumping animation when user tap on the animation which is really cool. for now I have the animation on 'Idle' mode

You may want to refer to the `rive` file => [Go to Rive](https://www.rive.app/community/1750-3467-bird/). And I renamed Rive `stateMachine` name to Bird. Everything else is the same.

summary => I want bird to jump when user tap on him :)

[image]

The code and the image may be little bit bigger. Sorry about that

```
class Favourites extends StatefulWidget {
  Favourites({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Favourites> createState() => _FavouritesState();
}

class _FavouritesState extends State<Favourites> {
  String animation = 'idle';
  SMIInput<String>? _birdInput;
  Artboard? _birdArtboard;

  void jump() {
    setState(() {
      _birdInput?.value = 'Pressed';
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rootBundle.load('assets/rive/bird.riv').then(
      (data) {
        final file = RiveFile.import(data);
        final artboard = file.mainArtboard;
        var controller = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(
          artboard,
          'Bird',
        );
        if (controller != null) {
          artboard.addController(controller);
          _birdInput = controller.findInput('Pressed');
        }
        setState(() => _birdArtboard = artboard);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final favourite = Provider.of<Favourite>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: const CustomAppBar(title: 'Favourites'),
      body: favourite.items.isEmpty
          ? Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 500,
                    child: _birdArtboard == null
                        ? const SizedBox()
                        : Center(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Rive(artboard: _birdArtboard!),
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                   NeumorphicButton(),
                ],
              ),
            )
          : CustomGrid(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the code just providing necessary part

Comment: I simplified the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open/run rive file on rive site, you can find that it is using `Trigger` variable for jumping and it is using `State Machine 1` state machine.

[image]

Next thing comes about declaring variable. You need to use `SMITrigger` data type for this and use `StateMachineController` to control the animation.

Use `.findSMI(..)` instead of `.findInput()` for `SMITrigger`.

To start animation on trigger, use

```
 trigger?.fire();
```

I will encourage you to take a look on editor and check input variable type while performing rive animation.

So the full widget that will provide animation is

```dart
class Favourites extends StatefulWidget {
  const Favourites({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Favourites> createState() => _FavouritesState();
}

class _FavouritesState extends State<Favourites> {
  String animation = 'idle';

  Artboard? _birdArtboard;
  SMITrigger? trigger;
  StateMachineController? stateMachineController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rootBundle.load('assets/rive/bird.riv').then(
      (data) {
        final file = RiveFile.import(data);
        final artboard = file.mainArtboard;
        stateMachineController =
            StateMachineController.fromArtboard(artboard, "State Machine 1");
        if (stateMachineController != null) {
          artboard.addController(stateMachineController!);
          trigger = stateMachineController!.findSMI('Pressed');

          stateMachineController!.inputs.forEach((e) {
            debugPrint(e.runtimeType.toString());
            debugPrint("name${e.name}End");
          });
          trigger = stateMachineController!.inputs.first as SMITrigger;
        }

        setState(() => _birdArtboard = artboard);
      },
    );
  }

  void jump() {
    trigger?.fire();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                height: 400,
                child: _birdArtboard == null
                    ? const SizedBox()
                    : Center(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            jump();
                          },
                          child: Rive(artboard: _birdArtboard!),
                        ),
                      ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Yeasing. Your help means a lot to me.

Comment: glad to help you out, you start with creating your simple rive animation then apply on flutter side [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69062813/10157127) might give a little push also you can follow rive officall video on yt

Comment: @vontdeux do a null check before using `!`