# Switch between different Rive Artboards in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, rive

I'm trying to reuse this Rive animation [Emoji Pack](https://editor.rive.app/preview/1302-2493-animated-emoji-pack/282367?mode=animate&artboard=) in Flutter. This animation, contains multiple artboards.
[image]

Using the RiveAnimation widget I can specify the specific artboard that will be shown. However, I'm wondering how to switch between artboards based on some events (e.g., button onPressed).

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Environment:**

```
flutter: 3.0.1
rive: ^0.8.4
```

Comment: You can create `State Machine` to control the animation

Comment: You follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69062813/10157127)  and try this [example](https://github.com/yeasin50/Rive_state_machine_example)

Comment: Thanks! I will check both your post and code